# jQuery UI Tabs select function not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I have the following jquery which is used to create tabs on my website (wrapped in document ready function):

```
$('#understanding-water-management').tabs({
    select: function(event, ui) {
        alert('hi');
    }
});
```

However, on my site the select function isn't been fired on tab change.  I have created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5Cv8c/1/) but this works as I would expect it to (it alerts hi on tab change).

The only difference between the two sites is that on my own website I have used a lighter version of jQuery UI where I have only downloaded the Core, Widget (from UI Core) and Tabs (from Widgets) options.  Is there any other option I need to download to get the `select` function above to work - I don't want to use the full jQuery UI as all I need is the tabs so want to make my js files as minimal as possible

Comment: What version of jQuery UI are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery UI 1.10 change the `select` to `beforeActivate` (if you want the function to fire before the tab is selected) or `activate` (if you want it to fire after the tab has been selected)

try

```
$('#understanding-water-management').tabs({
    beforeActivate: function(event, ui) {
        alert('hi');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to wrap your code inside DOM ready handler `$(function() {...});` to make sure all your DOM elements are loaded properly before executing your jQuery code:

```
$(function() {
    $('#understanding-water-management').tabs({
        select: function(event, ui) {
            alert('hi');
        }
    });
});
```

Your `jsFiddle` works because they've done above part for you by default when you include jQuery.